# Trouble connecting to my remote full node

Tags: full-node

I setup a full node on an Amazon EC2 instance running on Amazon Linux. I can see `monerod` running testnet in my SSH terminal (fully synchronized).

The security group for this instance has an inbound and outbound rule that allows all connection types, protocols, and ports from any source. I'll change this later but wanted to rule out a firewall issue blocking a port.

On my windows PC I try loading a wallet like so:
`./monero-wallet-cli.exe --testnet --daemon-host ec2-xxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com` replacing the `xxxxxxx` with my actual ec2 link.

I get:

**Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: http://ec2-xxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:28081. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or restart the wallet with the correct daemon address.**

I also tried using `--daemon-address` with ports 28080 and 28080 with no luck.

Not sure what else I can try to get this working, does anyone have any ideas or suggestions I can try?

Comment: Is the port opened (http://ismyportopen.com/)?

Comment: Port 28080 is open, 28081 is closed

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue. Testnet wallets connect on port 28081 by default, so seeing this port being closed made me try a few things. The one that worked, though I'm not sure exactly why, was to set `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0`. This opened port 28081 and everything works well now.

Comment: I have seen others solve the issue that way.  I run with `--rpc-bind-ip` and then the IP address of the node.  Of course, I'm running it locally with my local IP address, so maybe that wouldn't work for you.

Comment: By default, monerod binds on the loopback interface, so only local processes can reach it. Binding on an external interface (such as 0.0.0.0) means all other machines can reach it (including your own).